# Checking if an input is an Integer using exceptions - Java

Tags: java, exception, input, integer

My method must request input from the user, check if it is an integer, and if it is return that integer. I attempted this using a try catch and the InputMismatchException.

I am running into an issue when it loops, if I input a non integer, it continuously spits out "Invalid input" "Enter an integer: " instead of actually asking for one.

```
public int getInteger(){
    Scanner i = new Scanner(System.in);
    int value = 0;

    for(boolean test = false; test == false;){
        try{
        System.out.println("Enter an integer: ");
        value = i.nextInt();

        test = true;
        return value;
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e){System.out.println("Invalid input");}
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Solved my problem by initiating scanner i inside the for loop.

Comment: MattM - that is a bad solution.  And not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `i.nextLine();` at the end of the loop.

```
    catch(InputMismatchException e){System.out.println("Invalid input");}
    i.nextLine();
}
```

What that does is reads the new line character, left unread by `i.nextInt()`, from the input stream. It's also the reason your `i.nextInt()` keeps tripping on the subsequent calls.

Comment: No problem. If you want, you can also use `nextLine()` instead of `nextInt()` and parse the line using the `Integer.parseInt()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you call [`hasNextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29) before `nextInt()` instead of trying to catch the `Exception`. Something like,

```
public int getInteger() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
            return scan.nextInt();
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%s is not an int%n", scan.nextLine());
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Calling `next()` won't recover if the user entered something like "a b c" instead of a number.